# C# Adding a picturebox to a panel

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I have a panel, called panel3, which is found in 'Form1.cs'. In this panel, I have drawn 5 lines to represent a music staff.

Now I want to add the picture of the note pressed on a piano to the music staff. Basically, I want to add a picture box at a specific location on the music staff.

In order to do so, I created a method called 'addPictureBox' in 'Staff.cs' to build a picture box and place it on the panel everytime a key is pressed.

This is the relevant code. The problem is that the picture box is not displayed on the panel. Only the lines which were drawn earlier can be seen in panel3.

What can I do to solve this problem please? Why is the picturebox not displayed in panel3? Thanks.

**Edit**

Thanks for your help :)  I have solved the problem

Comment: From which event are you calling addPictureBox() ?

Comment: I am calling addPictureBox() from MouseUp event

Comment: Do you know how to use the debugger? It would be a lot easier for yourself, and faster, if you first tried debugging these things before asking stackoverflow for help. Stackoverflow is for when you don't know how to do something, or when something is happening which is illogical. Your problem is none of those; your problem is simply that you need to do some debugging.

Comment: I did debugging.  In the addPictureBox() method, the image is being assigned to the pNewImage.  Even the co-ordinates are being passed correctly.  However nothing comes up in panel3.

Comment: A lot of your class mates post very similar questions about this project.  Please use the [homework] tag.  And consider getting together with them so you can help each other.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO Its not good idea to place picture box - its not transparent. So I suggest you to draw notes manually. For example:

---

Create base note class:

```
public class Note
{
    public Point Location { get; set; } 

    public virtual void Draw(Graphics g)
    {

    }
}
```

---

Create notes, lets say simple, difficult and picture(which draws picture):

```
public class SimpleNote:Note
{
    public SimpleNote(Point position)
    {
        Location = position;
    }

    public override void Draw(Graphics g)
    {
        g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, Location.X, Location.Y, 5, 5);
        g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red), Location.X+5, Location.Y, Location.X+5, Location.Y-15);
    }
}

public class DifficultNote:Note
{
    public DifficultNote(Point position)
    {
        Location = position;
    }

    public override void Draw(Graphics g)
    {
        SimpleNote left = new SimpleNote(Location);
        SimpleNote right = new SimpleNote(new Point(Location.X + 20, Location.Y));

        left.Draw(g);
        right.Draw(g);
        g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red), Location.X+5, Location.Y - 15, Location.X+25, Location.Y-15);
    }
}

public class PictureNote:Note
{
    private Image _image;
    public PictureNote(Image image, Point position)
    {
        Location = new Point(position.X - image.Width/2, position.Y - image.Height/2);
        _image = image;
    }

    public override void Draw(Graphics g)
    {
        g.DrawImage(_image, Location);
    }
}
```

---

Add note list in Staff class and call draw methods in OnPaint method:

```
public List<Note> noteList = new List<Note>(); 
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    int yPos = kOffset + staffIndex * kStaffSpacing;
    for (int bars = 0; bars < 5; bars++)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 0, yPos, kStaffInPixels, yPos);
        yPos += kBarSpacing;
    }

    foreach (var note in noteList)
    {
        note.Draw(e.Graphics);
    }
}
```

and in your staff panel create mouse click event handler for example like this:

```
private void staff1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        staff1.noteList.Add(new SimpleNote(new Point(e.X, e.Y)));
    if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        staff1.noteList.Add(new DifficultNote(new Point(e.X, e.Y)));
    if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Middle)
            staff1.noteList.Add(new PictureNote(new Bitmap("c:\\note.png"), new Point(e.X, e.Y)));
       staff1.Invalidate();
}
```

---

Result (first is from picture, second difficult and third is simple):

[image]

P.s. code is not the best, I just illustrating my idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling:

```
pNewImage.BringToFront();
```

After

```
panel3.Controls.Add(pNewImage);
```